# Anticipating program crashes

Tags: debugging, crash, static-analysis, machine-code

I'm working on a program that should be able to tell if any program I run on my computer will crash.

Presumably it's possible to read in the machine code, build a model of the potential code paths, test each code path for behavior under standard and boundary conditions, map out the conditions that result in unhandled exceptions, and then trace all those steps backward to generate the required set up inputs and conditions that would trigger the exceptional code path to be taken. It's like using a fuzzing debugger, only more methodical. Sure it's a lot of work, but it should go very quickly on modern hardware.

A coworker said that what I'm trying to do is fundamentally impossible. That seems a little extreme to me. Given Moore's law curve of technology development, computing power that is out of reach will eventually become reality -- eventually. It would seem a bit of an overstatement to suggest that such a thing would remain forever *impossible*.

Why can't this be done?

Comment: Because if it could be done, you would have solved the Halting Problem. The Nobel Prize will be yours!

Comment: I don't want a nobel prize. I just want a verifiable computing environment.

Comment: Putting aside the huge amount of processing you're talking about, *sometimes* hardware doesn't do what it's supposed to do because of environmental conditions and programs crash.  You could have an analysis tool that just printed 'yes' it will crash.  The hard part would be predicting how long it would take before that happened....

Comment: Read Garey and Johnson: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Garey-Johnson

Comment: Read [Garey and Johnson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Garey-Johnson)

Comment: Just wondering if you've finished yet.

Comment: @BrandonLarson: When I was a kid I devised a smart & easy way to making computer programs with as little thinking and coding as possible: generating random sequences of bytes. The problem was, I couldn't know if they were useful and how. But the bigger problem was the realization of how many iterations and time the generator would need to produce any known to be useful piece of code of ~100 bytes. The problem is crazy big. If fuzzing is what you're after, you might be better off executing the code, noting missed paths, tweaking inputs/states to reach them, rerunning it and observing crashes.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a program :

```
accept integer i greater than 2
loop with k from 2 to 2*i
  is k prime?
    is 2*i-k prime?
      exit safely
end loop
do something nasty.
```

If you trace the input that cause this program to do something nasty, you have solved [Goldbach's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture). You can collect a Fields medal along with your Nobel prize.

This said, it is possible to verify that *some* programs do not do anything nasty. I and others are working on [a framework in which you can do just that, using various techniques](http://frama-c.com/). Some examples:

[This compression library could exhibit a memory error with input size 20, output size 40, but now it won't.](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2011/04/05/QuickLZ-1)

[This binary search could fail, but now it won't.](http://www.lri.fr/proval/gallery/BinarySearchACSL.fr.html)

Comment: Similar arguments can be made about optimizing compilers - the halting problem guarantees there is no optimal compiler, and yet in practice we all find optimizations to be quite useful.  The fact that you can't create a perfect defect analysis shouldn't get in the way of discovering, automatically, the problems that are tractable by human software developers.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the Holy Grails of computing and mathematics, known as the [Entscheidungsproblem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entscheidungsproblem).  You're not going to solve it.  The brightest minds in both fields spent many years on it, and proved that it could not be solved.  When nbt and Pascal Cuoq said you'd win the Nobel and Fields for doing so, they really meant it.

Answer (score 0):

> Presumably it's possible to read in the machine code, build a model of the potential code paths, test each code path for behavior under standard and boundary conditions, map out the conditions that result in unhandled exceptions, and then trace all those steps backward to generate the required set up inputs and conditions that would trigger the exceptional code path to be taken.

Yes, it is possible, despite what the theory folks say.   There are multiple companies selling products that do exactly what you are describing, among them Vericode, Coverity, Fortify, Klocwork, and Grammatech.

The theory says this is impossible, assuming you want something that is both [sound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness) and [complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness#Logical_completeness).   In practice, you can drop both soundness and completeness, so long as your false positive rate isn't too bad, and you will have customers lining up to buy your product.

Once you drop soundness and completeness, the impossibility theorems no longer hold, and you move into something much more like engineering than theory.

**Edit, for Alex's comment**
I will take the mathematicians shortcut, and say that since the original question is "Is it possible" the existence of several viable commercial products proves the answer is "yes".  The economic dependencies that might be created by using commercial software are beyond the scope of the original question.

Comment: And then you'll need to justify buying a tool without guarantees and hope there isn't any crazy bug left undiscovered after applying it.